# Getting childrens in all languages using Sitecore query

Tags: sitecore

How to get all childrens and grand childrens under home item in all languages if at all they have a version in the language?

I want to achieve this using Sitecore query.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
//Getting the default "en" language
var contextLanguage = Sitecore.Context.Language.Name;
string query = "/sitecore/content/home//*";

//Getting items in en language
List<Item> items = database.SelectItems(query).ToList();
foreach (var language in languages)
{
    //Getting items in all language other than the default en language
    if (!string.Equals(contextLanguage, language))
    {
        //Changing the context language so as to get items in the particular language
        Sitecore.Context.Language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(language);
        items.AddRange(database.SelectItems(query).ToList());
     }
}
//Ressetting the context to the default language
Sitecore.Context.Language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(contextLanguage);
```

Note: Here languages is a collection of all available languages in the site.

The above code is returning me each items 4 (because we have 4 languages) times when they don't have a version in particular language in the default en language only.

Note: I am using language fallback module in the site. Can that be a reason for this?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Most likely it is because of the fallback module. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Just a note: You should never use the descendants axes for everything under home, if you have more than 100 descendants. This will not perform and you should look into Sitecore.ContentSearch if Sitecore 7 or Lucene indexes if you are on Sitecore 6.

However if this is for a one time task or something similar you can do the following:

```
//Iterate through your item collection
foreach (Item item in items)
{
    //Iterate through the languages the item has
    foreach (var language in item.Languages)
    {
        Item itemInSpecifLanguage = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(item.ID, language);
        //Do whatever

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jens for your feedback.The above task is a one time task executed on a click of a custom command.We are ensuring that there wont be more than 100 items under home,we have also increased the query limit to 500 in the settings for safer side.So is the above way of iterating is the only way or can this be achieved by querying the database directly?

Comment: You could also use a [fast query](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query.pdf) but for the sake of a one time deal it probably does not make much difference